Unable to inject service into ConstraintValidator: jakarta.validation.ValidationException HV000064
I'm trying to set up a custom ConstraintValidator to check if a LocalDate is valid by delegating the validation logic to a service.
The validator is applied to a field in an @Entity. My goal is for the validation to execute during Hibernate's lifecycle events, such as before persisting or removing the entity.
However, when Hibernate attempts to execute the validation, the following exception occurs:

jakarta.validation.ValidationException: HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator: x.xx.xxx.util.validator.DateIsOpenValidator.

Here is the implementation of the validator:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DateIsOpenValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DateIsOpen, LocalDate> {
  private final EntryService entryService;

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(LocalDate date, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return entryService.validateDateIsOpen(date);
  }
}

The exception suggests that the validator cannot be instantiated. My understanding is that using dependency injection for a ConstraintValidator is possible, as explained in the following sources:

Injecting Spring Dependencies into ConstrantValidator
Spring-Boot How to properly inject javax.validation.Validator

Additionally, the Spring Framework documentation indicates that configuring a Bean Validation Provider should suffice for enabling dependency injection in validators.
Am I missing a configuration step or misusing the approach in some way? How can I resolve this issue to allow entryService to be properly injected into the ConstraintValidator?
I have tested many approaches, but these are the most relevant.
Configuring the Validator with LocalValidatorFactoryBean
I have configured the default Validator bean using LocalValidatorFactoryBean:
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}

Adding a No-Args Constructor
I attempted to add a no-args constructor to the ConstraintValidator implementation. However, this approach predictably resulted in a null EntryService:
public class DateIsOpenValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DateIsOpen, LocalDate> {

    private EntryService entryService;

    public DateIsOpenValidator() {}

    public DateIsOpenValidator(EntryService entryService) {
        this.entryService = entryService;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(LocalDate date, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (entryService == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("EntryService has not been initialized");
        }
        return entryService.validateDateIsOpen(date);
    }
}

UPDATE:
Tell Hibernate to match the validator
As stated in this stack overflow question, we can tell Hibernate which Validator to use like so:
  @Bean
  @Lazy
  public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(final Validator validator) {
    return hibernateProperties ->
        hibernateProperties.put("jakarta.persistence.validation.factory", validator);
  }


Observations:

The LocalValidatorFactoryBean configuration alone does not resolve the issue.
Adding a no-args constructor "works around" the ConstraintValidator instantiation exception, but fails to inject dependencies.
This works in the surface; I'm almost tempted to respond to my own question and accept the answer, but I suspect I'm missing something due to the lack of information online.


You are trying to use constructor injection, I don't think that is going to work in this case as this is not a normal bean autowiring setup, this is a custom implementation. You will probably need to use autowired annotations on the fields, just like the documentation shows you.

@Gimby I suspect that's not the case, the docs might be using @Autowired for clarity only. As the last workaround I listed in my question actually does resolve the issue, so the CustomValidator is being interpreted as a bean and the dependencies can be injected, I'm just not sure of the correctness of the solution.
